# Safari CMD+F can't search text inside list's

Tags: javascript, swift, search, safari, automator

How it looks in [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tndaZ.png) and in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDOmo.png)

Even `Window.find("some text to find")` working in the same way. May be i miss something in `Develop` settings, `Experimental features`...

I enjoy using Safari and it suits my needs, but this behaviour is frustrating me.

Any suggestions for implementing this feature via Apple Automator, simple Swift plugin for text searching or some JavaScript code to paste directly into console ?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the page, and what UI element that is, how is anybody possibly going to be able to help you?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this. This problem occurs with the `<select>` tag. This [page](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select) as an example